# Given an array A, how to find for each element A[i], the number of numbers in A[0] ... A[i-1] that are smaller than A[i]?

Tags: algorithm

Given an array `A`, how to find for each element `A[i]`, the number of numbers in `A[0] ... A[i-1]` that are smaller than `A[i]`? Is there an algorithm that is faster than the naive `O(n^2)` algorithm?

For example, if `A = [1,2,3,2,1]`, the expected output would be `[0,1,2,1,0]`.

Comment: Please show an example and also your expected result

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi, updated above. For example, if A = [1,2,3,2,1], the expected output would be [0,1,2,1,0]. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very good DSA question. The O(n^2) complexity solution is obvious.
For O(nlogn) solution, you should take your reference from counting the number of inversions in an array.

I hope this helps: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/